# Timing tests for a threadpool : single thread vs callback tp vs future tp

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14, threadpool

I have 3 unit tests case for this code ThreadPool in https://github.com/spakai/threadpool_future

```
   class ThreadPoolTest : public Test {
    public:
        ThreadPool pool;
        std::condition_variable wasExecuted;
        std::mutex m;
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::thread>> threads; 

        unsigned int count{0};

        void incrementCountAndNotify() {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
            ++count;
            std::cout << count << std::endl;
            wasExecuted.notify_all();
        }

        void waitForNotificationOrFailOnTimeout(unsigned expectedCount, int milliseconds=80000) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
            ASSERT_THAT(wasExecuted.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(milliseconds), [&] { return count == expectedCount; }), Eq(true));      

        } 

        bool hasDuplicates(const std::vector<int> & birthdays) {
            std::set<int> uniqueBirthdays(birthdays.begin(), birthdays.end());
            return (uniqueBirthdays.size() != birthdays.size());
        }

        std::vector<int> generateNumbers(const int popSize) {
            std::vector<int> list;
            std::random_device rd;
            std::default_random_engine dre(rd());
            std::uniform_int_distribution<int> di(0,365);
            for(int i{0}; i < popSize ; i++) {
                list.push_back(di(dre));
            } 
            return list;
        }

        void TearDown() override {
            for (auto& t: threads) t->join();
        }
};



TEST_F(ThreadPoolTest,TimingTestWithFuture) {
    pool.start(4);
    std::vector<std::future<unsigned long long>> results;
    auto work = [](int n) {
      unsigned long long factorial = 1;
      for(int i = 1; i <=n; ++i) {
        factorial *= i;
      }

      return factorial;

    };


    TestTimer timer("4-sized-TP with Future",0);
    for (int i = 5; i < 60 ; i++) {
        results.push_back(pool.submit(work,i));
    }


    for(unsigned int i = 0; i< results.size(); i++) {
        results.at(i).get();
    }
}

TEST_F(ThreadPoolTest,TimingTestWithCallback) {
    pool.start(4);
    std::vector<unsigned long long> results;
    TestTimer timer("4-sized-TP-Callback",0);
    for (int n = 5; n < 60 ; n++) {
        auto work = [&]() {
            unsigned long long factorial = 1;
            for(int i = 1; i <=n; ++i) {
              factorial *= i;
            }
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m); 
                results.push_back(factorial);
            }
            incrementCountAndNotify();
        };

        pool.add(work);
    }

    waitForNotificationOrFailOnTimeout(55);
}

TEST_F(ThreadPoolTest,TimingTestWithoutTP) {

    std::vector<unsigned long long> results;
    auto work = [](int n) {
      unsigned long long factorial = 1;
      for(int i = 1; i <=n; ++i) {
        factorial *= i;
      }

      return factorial;

    };


    TestTimer timer("In Sequence",0);
    for (int i = 5; i < 60 ; i++) {
        results.push_back(work(i));
    }

     for(unsigned int i = 0; i< results.size(); i++) {
        results.at(i);
    }

}
```

I am running on a 4 CPU machine. I am getting timing results that shows that the single thread is fastest , and the one returning the future the slowest.

4-sized-TP with Future Time taken = 2.364ms

4-sized-TP-Callback Time taken = 1.103ms

In Sequence Time taken = 0.026ms

I was expecting the timings will be in reverse order. 
Is the way I am doing the tests wrong ? Or is it my code?

New tests which would be CPU heavy

```
TEST_F(ThreadPoolTest,BirthdayParadoxInSequenceTimingTest) {

    std::vector<int> results;

    TestTimer timer("Birthday Paradox :: In Sequence",0);

    std::vector<int> popList = {10,23,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,120,150};
    for(auto it=popList.begin(); it!=popList.end(); ++it) {
        int id = *it;
        int dup{0};
        for(int i{0}; i< 100000; i++) {
            auto list = generateNumbers(id);
            if(hasDuplicates(list)) ++dup;
        }

        results.push_back(dup);
    }

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i< results.size(); i++) {
            results.at(i);
        }
}

TEST_F(ThreadPoolTest,BirthdayParadoxTPWithFutureTimingTest) {
    std::vector<int> popList = {10,23,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,120,150};

    pool.start(4);
    std::vector<std::future<int>> results;

    TestTimer timer("4-sized-TP with Future",0);

    for(auto it=popList.begin(); it!=popList.end(); ++it) {
        int id = *it;
        auto work = [&](int pop) {
            int dup{0};
            for(int i{0}; i < 100000 ; i++) {
                auto list = generateNumbers(pop);
                if(hasDuplicates(list)) ++dup; 
            }

            return dup;

        };

        results.push_back(pool.submit(work,id));        
    } 

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i< results.size(); i++) {
        results.at(i).get();
    }
} 



TEST_F(ThreadPoolTest,BirthdayParadoxTPWithCallBackTimingTest) {
    std::vector<int> popList = {10,23,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,120,150};

    pool.start(4);
    std::vector<int> results;

    TestTimer timer("4-sized-TP with Callback",0);

    for(auto it=popList.begin(); it!=popList.end(); ++it) {
        int id = *it;
        auto work = [&,id]() {
            int dup{0};
            for(int i{0}; i < 100000 ; i++) {
                auto list = generateNumbers(id);
                if(hasDuplicates(list)) ++dup; 

                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m); 
                    results.push_back(dup);

                }
            }

            incrementCountAndNotify();
        };

        pool.add(work);       
    } 

    waitForNotificationOrFailOnTimeout(12);
}
```

Results though still not I was expecting

In Sequence Time taken = 37555.7ms

4-sized-TP with Future Time taken = 62544.8ms

4-sized-TP with Callback Time taken = 62563.6ms

The full code and tests are in https://github.com/spakai/threadpool_future

Comment: Computing a factorial is hardly a challenging task for the CPU.  All your overhead is happening in context switching and locks.  Try throwing a taxing problem at it instead.

Comment: ok, i changed to something CPU heavy. The timings are still off. when i use top -  the sequence test shows close to 100% CPU, the Future  and Callback shows close to 400%. I've updated with the new tests above.

Comment: I tried to replicate your behaviour. In the files in the repo are some mistakes. First TThreadPoolTest.cpp is missing a `#include <random>` and second the `sources` variable in the cmakelists.txt need to contain TestTimer.cpp.

The sad news is, that i get a similar timing behaviour.

Comment: I'll commit those. Thanks. How many cores do your system have ? I was thinking that maybe i should not assign 4 to my TP , since i have only 4 cores. 1 is taken away by the test, 1 by the TP main program , that should leave me with only 2 for the threads .

Comment: I test with 2 cores at the moment. I don't think that the problem is with the amount of hardwarethreads, but with the locking in the task queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the birthday paradox problem, that you choose is not a challenging task for the cpu either. But to understand the problem you see, we first have to make some changes to the code.

We want to measure the time it takes for our algorithm to finish. Memory allocations are expensive and should be avioded in parts of the program that are repeated very often.
Creating vectors or increasing their size will always trigger memory allocation. The same is also true for creating a set. To remove the momory allocations i modified your code to look like this:

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <random>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

#include "ThreadPool.h"
#include "TestTimer.h"


const unsigned int runs = 100000;

using namespace testing;

class ThreadPoolTest : public Test {
    public:
        ThreadPool pool;
        std::condition_variable wasExecuted;
        std::mutex m;
        std::mutex n;
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::thread>> threads;
        std::vector<int> popList = {10,11,12,23};

        unsigned int count{0};

        void incrementCountAndNotify() {
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
                ++count;
            }
            wasExecuted.notify_all();
        }

        void waitForNotificationOrFailOnTimeout(unsigned expectedCount, int milliseconds=80000) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
            ASSERT_THAT(wasExecuted.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(milliseconds), [&] { return count == expectedCount; }), Eq(true));

        }

        bool hasDuplicates(const std::vector<int> & birthdays) {
            //This way to check for duplicates is very expensive, since it allocates new memory and copies all values around
            //std::set<int> uniqueBirthdays(birthdays.begin(), birthdays.end());
            //return (uniqueBirthdays.size() != birthdays.size());
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < birthdays.size(); i++) {
                for(unsigned int j = i+1; j < birthdays.size(); j++) {
                    if(birthdays[i]==birthdays[j]) return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        //I added the parameter list, to avoid the allocation of new memory
        //The list will also have the needed size, so that we dont need to it here
        std::vector<int> generateNumbers(std::vector<int>& list) {
            //It is not exactly specified how the random_device works, it may read from /dev/random, which can not be done in parallel
            //To make the measurements compareable over multiple machiens i removed this code
            //std::random_device rd;
            std::default_random_engine dre(0);
            std::uniform_int_distribution<int> di(0,365);
            int counter = 0;
            for(int& i : list) {
                i = di(dre);
            }
            return list;
        }

        void TearDown() override {
            for (auto& t: threads) t->join();
        }
};


TEST_F(ThreadPoolTest,BirthdayParadoxInSequenceTimingTest) {

    std::vector<int> results;

    TestTimer timer("Birthday Paradox :: In Sequence",0);

    for(auto it=popList.begin(); it!=popList.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << "TID " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

        int id = *it;
        int dup{0};
        std::vector<int> list(id); //Allocate memory in the right size only once for all 100000 runs
        for(int i{0}; i < runs ; i++) {
                generateNumbers(list);
            if(hasDuplicates(list)) ++dup;
        }

        results.push_back(dup); //This push_back is ok, since it is only called 4 times in total
    }

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i< results.size(); i++) {
            results.at(i);
        }
}

TEST_F(ThreadPoolTest,BirthdayParadoxTPWithFutureTimingTest) {
    pool.start(4);
    std::vector<std::future<int>> results;

    TestTimer timer("4-sized-TP with Future",0);

    for(auto it=popList.begin(); it!=popList.end(); ++it) {
        int id = *it;
        auto work = [&](int pop) {
            std::cout << "TID " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

            int dup{0};
            std::vector<int> list(pop); //Same as above
            for(int i{0}; i < runs ; i++) {
                generateNumbers(list);
                if(hasDuplicates(list)) ++dup;
            }

            return dup;

        };

        results.push_back(pool.submit(work,id));
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i< results.size(); i++) {
        results.at(i).get();
    }
}


TEST_F(ThreadPoolTest,BirthdayParadoxTPWithCallBackTimingTest) {
    pool.start(4);
    std::vector<int> results;

    TestTimer timer("4-sized-TP with Callback",0);

    for(auto it=popList.begin(); it!=popList.end(); ++it) {
        int id = *it;
        auto work = [&,id]() {
            std::cout << "TID " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

            int dup{0};
            std::vector<int> list(id); //Same here too
            for(int i{0}; i < runs ; i++) {
                generateNumbers(list);
                if(hasDuplicates(list)) ++dup;

                        {
                        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(n);
                        results.push_back(dup);
                    }
            }

            incrementCountAndNotify();
        };

        pool.add(work);
    }
    waitForNotificationOrFailOnTimeout(4);
}
```

Now, that we got our memory managment right, we can start to reason about the runtimes. I ran the code with 2 Cores and Hyperthreading, so we would expect a speedup of 2 or higher if we use multithreading. Let's look at the results:

```
Birthday Paradox :: In Sequence Time taken = 680.96ms
4-sized-TP with Future Time taken = 1838.28ms
4-sized-TP with Callback Time taken = 1861.07ms
```

If i limit the amount of threads in the threadpool to one, then the runtimes of all versions are nearly the same.

The reason we see this unintuitive behaviour is, that the problem is memory bound. The reason for the speed loss is in the checking for duplicates.

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < birthdays.size(); i++) {
    for(unsigned int j = i+1; j < birthdays.size(); j++) {
        if(birthdays[i]==birthdays[j]) return true;
    }
}
```

The access of the birthdays is nicely aligned in memory. If more than one thread is running, the algorithm does not gain speed, since all of them are only waiting for the values. And even worse is, that different threads are reading from different locations and therefore, they can trash the cachelines, that may be used by the other threads. That is the reason, you see the performance drop.

Comment: thanks OutOfBound, never crossed my mind that it would be memory. Will try the above , and get another example that is really CPU heavy.